# How does this map give a circle centered at $1/2$ of radius $1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$f(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$$

Then determine the image of $L=\{z \in \Bbb{C} : \text{Im $z$ = -1}\}$

I know I take points $-1-i,-i,1-i$
which get mapped to

$$\frac{1-2i}{5},0,\frac{1+2i}{5}$$

respectively. How do I know this amounts to the circle centered at $1/2$ of radius $1/2$?

Comment: What about showing that all three image points have the same distance $1/2$ to the center?

Comment: @MartinR I tried showing this but it gets super messy, is there a simple way of doing so

Comment: For $w = (1-2i)/5$ is $w-1/2 = (-3-4i)/10$ and $|w-1/2| = \sqrt{3^2+4^2}/10 = 1/2$. Not extremely messy ...

Comment: where did you get $w-1/2..$ from @MartinR

Comment: $|w-1/2| = 1/2$ is the circle with center $1/2$ and radius $1/2$.

Comment: But I don’t know how to get the center nor radius so you’re assuming the center is $1/2$? @MartinR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you have a solution already, but if you want a general method you can apply in lots of different situations and which doesn’t require guesswork, then try the following:

Start by setting $$w=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$$ where $w=u+iv$, and rearrange to make $z$ the subject. So you get
$$z=\frac{iw+i}{w-1}$$

Now identify (in this case) the imaginary part of this in terms of $u$ and $v$ (after a bit of algebra) and apply the relevant condition.

In this case, $$Im(z)=\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{(u-1)^2+v^2}=-1$$

This leads directly to the equation of the image:
$$(u-\frac12)^2+v^2=\frac14$$

So you didn’t need to know in advance that you would get a circle centred at $\frac12$ with radius $\frac12$

Comment: How’d you get to the Imz step from z= I’m terms of w step?

Comment: Did you let w=u+vi and mult by complex conjugate ?

Comment: Yes express the fraction in terms of $u$ and $v$ and multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator, then extract the imaginary part

Answer (score 1):

One can use that Möbius transformations are angle-preserving: $f$ maps the (extended) imaginary axis to the (extended) real axis, and $L$ intersects the imaginary axis at a right angle. It follows that $f(L)$ is a line or circle which intersects the real axis at a right angle.

Now compute $f(-i) = 0$ and $f(\infty) = 1$ to conclude that $f(L)$ is a disk with center $1/2$ and radius $1/2$.

Comment: So do we always use points i and $\infty$?

Comment: @MyMathYourMath: There is no recipe which “always” works. Here $i$ and $\infty$ are chosen because they lie on the extended imaginary axis *and* on the extended line $L$, so that the image points are where $f(L)$ intersects the real axis.

Answer (score 1):

We seek to show that $$\bigg|f(x-i)-\frac 12\bigg|=\frac 12; x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Note that...
$$f(x-i) = \frac x{x-2i} $$
So

$$\begin{align}
f(x-i)-\frac 12 =& \frac 12 \bigg[ \frac{2x}{x-2i} -  \frac{x-2i}{x-2i} 
\bigg]
\\=& \frac 12 \bigg[\frac{x+2i}{x-2i} \bigg]
\end{align}$$
And...
$$\begin{align}
\bigg|f(x-i)-\frac 12\bigg| =& \frac 12  \frac{|x+2i|}{|x-2i|}
\\=& \frac 12 
\end{align}$$

Comment: but where does the $1/2$ come from in the first place? if I do not know the center and radius of the circle.